# Create a Synonym for a database / Change DB views point to

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, synonym

I know databases aren't supported by `CREATE SYNONYM`, but I'm looking to achieve the functionality this would provide.

We've got Database A which contains views to tables on Database B. The trouble is "Database B" isn't always called "Database B". We use database projects for deployments, which at the moment fall over with an "Invalid Object Name" error if there isn't a "Database B".

The workaround at the moment is to open up the .dbschema file and do a find and replace. I guess another option would be to create a load of table synonyms.

What's the best way of changing the database a number of views reference without changing each view individually?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synonyms are a good way to do this.  You have to create the synonyms at the object level though (as you've discovered).  An easy way to do this would be to write a script that runs through the list of tables in DatabaseB (from your example) and creates a synonym for each one in DatabaseA.  Keep the *name* of the synonym the same so the code in your views doesn't have to change.  For instance, you you have tbl_a, tbl_b, and tbl_c in DatabaseB, you'd want your script to eventually do the following:

```
create synonym [otherDb].[tbl_a] for [DatabaseB].[schemaB].[tbl_a]
create synonym [otherDb].[tbl_b] for [DatabaseB].[schemaB].[tbl_b]
create synonym [otherDb].[tbl_c] for [DatabaseB].[schemaB].[tbl_c]
```

Now, in your view code, you'll always use [otherDb].[tbl_a], [otherDb].[tbl_b], and [otherDb].[tbl_c].  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think it would be better to use something like
   `create synonym otherDb_tbl_a for [DatabaseB].[schemaB]`.[tbl_a]
? Not sure, but using the . notation results (SQL Server 2012) in 
   `The specified schema name "otherDb" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it`.

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion, so feel free to use whatever you want. As far as the error you got, if you didn't create the schema otherDb in your current database, that would be a problem. But the point of the answer to the original question was to provide a consistent interface for objects in the current db (i.e. views, stored procedures, etc) while being able to change the location of the other database. So, in this case, "otherDb" is just a placeholder for whatever schema is being used in those objects.

Comment: My bad, I simply did not know (or did not think about the fact) that synonyms can use a schema, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Last year I helped my current client with the implementation of a very similar design. We wrote a set of functions and stored procedures which generate the views automatically. Whenever you need to change the target database it generates the code to drop and recreate all of the views.

The code wasn't too difficult. It just uses the system tables to generate view code. I also wrote a Powershell prototype that uses SMO to do the same thing. The key is to have it automated to the point of requiring a single call so that you can do it easily and accurately.

We also included an exception table that used a pattern match of tables to exclude from view generation. It included a schema column and a table name column, each of which accepted `LIKE` patterns, so you could put "my_schema" and "%" to exclude all tables in the my_schema schema.

One master stored procedure accepted a target database name and would generate the entire script. Once the script is generated you can run it in SSMS or have that part automated as well.

This whole thing would be even easier if you just wanted to generate synonyms. We were using views so that we could change column lists, etc. and have the view DB look different than the target DB where needed.